# Using mailto breaks fading page transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you click on a link, it fades the page out and takes you to the new page. This works fine when you're being taken away to another site.

However, this does not work at all with a simple `<a href="mailto:hello@example.com">`. Why? Because you're not actually going anywhere. As a result, you get left with a blank page and an open mail client. Here is an example:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/n6KGf/)

```
function fadeAndGo(x) {

        $(x).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = this.href;
        $('.wrapper').fadeOut(function(){
            window.location = href;

        });
    });
}

fadeAndGo('a');
```

Would it be possible, instead of targeting all 'a' tags, target those with an attribute of `href`? Or choose to ignore those links that begin with `mailto:`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm no JS expert, but could this be done by giving the HTML anchor a class?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is on WordPress, so I'd like to keep it dynamic rather than change classes with each new anchor tag.

Comment: you'd only have to set the class for the mailto anchor, the rest would remain unaffected.
I cant imagine you use many mailto links on one page..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, only with CSS selector. jQuery will take care of the browser compatibility i guess, otherwise it will work on IE9+

```
fadeAndGo("a:not([href^='mailto:'])");
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `a:not([href^='mailto:']) `?

Comment: It's still not right. Try `fadeAndGo("a:not([href^='mailto:'])");
`

Comment: Check out the jquery selector compatibility, i cannot say.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the href attribute before changing the `window.location` value:

```
$('.wrapper').fadeOut(function () {
        if (href.indexOf('mailto') == -1) {
            window.location = href;
        }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/n6KGf/6/)

Comment: Again, does not seem to work on the anchor that's not a `mailto`: http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/n6KGf/4/

Comment: @tmyie Sorry, I posted the wrong link. See the fiddle in my answer now

Comment: Is there a way to have it outside the fadeOut function, so it only fades out if `indexOf?`

Answer (score 0):

<s>This should work:</s>

<s>`fadeAndGo('a[href^="http"]');`</s>

<s>[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/n6KGf/5/)</s>

**EDIT:** It just occurred to me that this won't work with links containing relative URLs, so I'd advise going with @Germain's answer instead.